# C++ operator overload template with different arguments

Tags: c++, templates, arguments, operator-keyword

I'm discovering C++ and I would like to create a mini mathematic Matrix librairy using templates.

Here, I want to overload the operator*.

If i describe a matrix like this: `M(y, x)` with `M` the matrix name, `y` and `x` the height and the width, a matrix multiplication should look like that:

```
M(a, b) * N(b, c) = R(a, c)
```

Currently I have this code:

```
template<unsigned int y, unsigned int x>
class Matrix
{
public:
    Matrix() { }
    ~Matrix() { }

    Matrix<y, x2>& operator*(const Matrix<y2, x2>& right)
    {
        // code...  
    }
private:
    std::array<std::array<double, x>, y>    m_values;
};
```

So I would like to be able to multiply two differents matrix like that:

```
Matrix<3, 4> m;
Matrix<4, 2> n;

// fill the matrix with values

Matrix<3, 2> o = m * n;
```

I've searched but I didn't find the answer to this question (maybe because I don't really know what I must search exactly).

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make your `operator*` a *template member function*, something like so:

```
template <unsigned int y2, unsigned int x2>
Matrix<y, x2> operator*(const Matrix<y2, x2>& right)
{
    // code...  
}
```

Notice that the return type is no longer a reference, as `operator*` should return a new value -- if you like, you can define a complementary `operator*=` which modifies the LHS matrix in-place.

Another thing to notice is that matrix multiplication only makes sense if the dimensions of the matrices agree: that is, if the number of columns in the LHS matches the number of rows in the RHS. To enforce this, you could use a `static_assert` within your member function to make sure that the template parameters agree:

```
template <unsigned int y2, unsigned int x2>
Matrix<y, x2> operator*(const Matrix<y2, x2>& right)
{
    static_assert(y2 == x, "Matrix dimensions mismatched");
    // code...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly simple, define `operator*` as a function template. Example free function template:

```
template<unsigned y1, unsigned x1, unsigned y2, unsigned x2>
Matrix<y1, x2> operator*(Matrix<y1, x1> const& l, Matrix<y2, x2> const& r)
{
    // static_assert(x1 == y2, "Matrices cannot be multiplied");
    Matrix<y1, x2> ret{};
    // multiply
    return ret;
}
```

Please note that `operator*` returns by value. this is especially important since you return a different type and have no object to return a reference to (idiomatic correctness aside).